# jQuery: Prevent jump on <a> tag if href only contains #

Tags: jquery, anchor

If an a tag has a hash set in the href, I want to prevent it to jump page to top upon click. So if user clicks on:

```
<a href="#">Hello</a>
```

Nothing should happen.

However:

```
<a href="#target">Lorem</a>
```

Should work as normal behavior.

Comment: Why do you need a link here? If it does nothing?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda It is used for a drop-down menu click...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you can do that rather easily

```
$('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Preventing the default action on all anchors with only a hash as a href will get rid of the scrolling to the top of the page for those anchors

In plain javascript assuming support for `querySelector` and `addEventListener`, it would look like

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]');

for ( var i=anchors.length; i--; ) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', fn, false);
}

function fn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Another option would be a delegated event handler, as mentioned in the comments

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href="#"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Using the DOM directly instead that would look something like

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clicked = event.target;

    while ( clicked ) {
        if (clicked.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A' &&
            clicked.getAttribute('href') === '#') {
            event.preventDefault();
            break;
        }
        clicked = clicked.parentNode;
    }
});
```

As should be obvious, the delegated handler would capture **all** clicks and do some checking to see if the target was an anchor or within an anchor, with a href of just `#`.
I wouldn't think it would be more efficient unless there is a whole lot of anchors in the DOM.

Comment: Ah! Will this prevent any other actions from triggering? For example, if I have <a href="#" id="trigger"> and I set an onclick on #trigger, will this cancel that action?

Comment: Nope, only default actions.

Comment: Very nice, works great. Just for completion, how do I do this in pure javascript?

Comment: This would add a handler for every matched element. Wouldn't a delegated event be better? #curious

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: jQuery **is** pure JavaScript. If you want to know how to do it purely with the DOM API, you'd use `document.querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener` (or -- shudder -- `attachEvent` on older IE) and `preventDefault()` (or `returnValue = false` on old IE). Or as Mackan points out, a single handler on `document` that then looks to see if it should prevent the default.

Comment: @Mackan You should post an answer demonstration how to use a single handler.

Comment: @Mackan - depends, what is worse, an event handler on each anchor, or capturing all clicks on the document and checking the event.target for a matching href attribute ?

Comment: @GaryWoods I asked out of curiosity. Since I tend to use delegated events myself I was curious if there are any reason, in cases like this, not to use it. Might add an answer if this is still active tomorrow though.

Comment: @Mackan - And there are good reasons in my opinion to not always use delegated event handlers, it depends on how many elements would have a seperate event handler attached, and how far up you would have to delegate, and how many unmatched events would be triggered and checked etc.

Comment: Maybe @T.J.Crowder knows more about the specifics regarding efficiency ?

Comment: @adeneo: In my experience, delegated click handling is never a performance problem. A click is a user action, and so is judged relative to human time, not computer time. The click's going to bubble anyway, so the only extra time really is the loop checking to see whether we care about the click, and even in the most complex page, it's going to be -- what -- 20, 30 iterations, tops? (One iteration per parent/child link, DOMs don't tend to be **massively** deep.) Doesn't make delegation necessarily the right answer, just a useful alternative, particularly with good lib support like jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - but have you ever experienced multiple handlers on each element to be a performance problem? I agree that it's useful, and I use delegated handlers sometimes on non-dynamic elements myself, but mostly when I can delegate to for instance an UL for all the LI's it contains etc. not when I have to delegate to the document and capture every click, even if I doubt I would ever notice a difference either way ?

Comment: @adeneo: As I say, delegation isn't necessarily the right answer. :-) 99% of the time, unless elements are being added and remove dynamically, I'll reach for the direct handler, although as I get more comfortable with delegation, I do it more. One reason for using direct handlers that isn't exemplified by *this* question is: Suppose I want to handle the click and stop propagation? With a delegated handler, the click's already propagated from the element to where I'm handling it, all I can do is keep it from going even further. As ever, a matter of picking the right tool for the specific job.

Comment: @adeneo: I didn't answer your question, sorry: *Yes*, I've experienced direct handlers being a problem, but **very rarely**, and it relates to the other use of delegation that I didn't mention above: If we're talking **thousands** of elements (a big table, for instance), delegation really help keep memory use down. Again, not the use case here, presumably, although I suppose the OP didn't tell us what the links were... I had no issue with your original answer. :-) But I'd upvote it again if I could thanks to your edits.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the clarification, and the edit, that version looks a lot cleaner, I just copy/pasted a "closest" version from another question.

Answer (score 1):

Use "javascript:;" or "javascript.void(0)":

```
<a href="javascript:;">Hello</a>
<a href="javascript.void(0)">Hello</a>
```

Comment: I need to target all <a> tags on my site that has href="#" -- your solution is an inline hack that does not target the href with the hash.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: What makes `javascript:;` more of hack than a `#` value that you prevent from doing what it normally does?